# How to `git reset` After `git merge --no-commit --no-ff`

Tags: git, git-merge, git-reset

I am a newbie to git.
I was working on a branch that involved lot of moving around of the code, including deletion of old and addition of new files. Therefore I decided to do a dry-run of git merge before actually merging:

I ran `git merge --no-commit --no-ff <myBranchName>`. After I ran this, it showed me some conflicts. Then I did git status and result was:

```
My-Macbook-pro:[master] $ git status
# On branch master
# You have unmerged paths.
#   (fix conflicts and run "git commit")
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   modified:   common/TP.php
#   deleted:    common/model/Job/Request.php
#   new file:   common/DP.php
#
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
#
#   both modified:      .gitignore
#   both added:         build/release/current/production.sql
#   deleted by them:    common/Service/DFPASPAdapter.php
#   both modified:      common/Ze.php
#   deleted by them:    common/model/provider/DFPASP.php
```

Then to undo `git add`(which happened because of the `git merge` dry run), I ran `git reset HEAD`. But later on I realized/learnt that in order to get back to the stage the master branch was in before merge(ie exactly same as what is committed to master), I will need to run `git reset --hard HEAD`
After I ran the hard reset, `git status` shows the following:

```
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   build/release/current/upgrade.php
#   common/F1.php
#   common/F2.php
#   common/F3.php
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

The above files F1, F2, F3 and upgrade.php were added in the branch that I was working on. I was hoping that `git reset --hard HEAD` will make the `master` branch forget about anything related to the branch I was trying to merge (dry run).

Is this something that is possible? 
Is there something I am missing in the concept? And am I left with the only option of removing the files manually? 
Any help in making me understand more will be great! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git doesn't know about files not in the index. To remove files unrelated to the current branch, including non-tracked ones, run

```
git clean -fd .
```